# Flex 4.6 and AS3 Calling method from another mxml file

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I have two files,

FloorplansMaster and Floorplans.

In my FloorplansMaster I have this method inside my script tags:

```
public function changeView(): void
{
     var floorplans:Floorplans = new Floorplans();

     floorplans.changeView();

}
```

and I am trying to call the method changeView in the Floorplans file, which looks like this:

```
public function changeView():void
            {
                trace("Here");
            }
```

But I keep getting this error:

```
Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference.
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You apparently are not creating the `var floorplans`. Do you ever call the function where that is initialized?

Comment: Based on the code you've shared, this should work fine.  Have you tried debugging?  What line throws the error?  You'll need to share that part of the code before anyone can help you.

Comment: As Brian said this should work fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Flex developers often try to access view elements before they're created.

Try calling the method in a creationComplete handler instead.